Podman Quadlet with pod template
I am trying to create a template mypod@.pod file. In the document, we have seen an example of using template with @.container.
I have a service that I want to replicate into multiple instances. The service itself comprises of several running containers, e.g. for database and web app.
I tried to create mypod@.pod, but the service created has the name mypod@-pod.service, so I cannot run systemctl start mypod@team1.service directly; the pod service has the "-pod" suffice to it, so a unit file "mypod@-pod.service" was created. I then manually override the service name
[Pod]
ServiceName=mypod@

Then I can see a service unit mypod@.serice was created. However, when I ran systemctl start mypod@team1.service, it does not work, and I only see the message that it failed to start.
Dec 31 22:46:21 thinkpad-l13 systemd[1917]: mypod@team1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 31 22:46:21 thinkpad-l13 systemd[1917]: mypod@team1.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 31 22:46:21 thinkpad-l13 systemd[1917]: mypod@team1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Is there a way to achieve this? If not, what is the alternative to package/replicate a collection of services?
